# How would I gradually lighten the bottom border of an image with OpenCV?

Tags: c#, opencv

For example, I have an image with 1000 rows. Row 900 should look like the original. I have an alpha and beta I want to apply on row 1000 to 100%, to row 950 to 50%, to row 925 to 25%. In other words: I want to blend the lower 10% of the image with a linear gradient. Is there a generic way in OpenCV without having to modify each discrete pixel and without first generating a Mat with the same size as the original?

I'm using the OpenCVSharp wrapper in C#.

Comment: With C++ API it is simple. But with C#...

Comment: Why is that? I know, there are some exotic overloads OpenCVSharp does not support (yet). Which one are you referring to? Can you post an answer with C++, please? I'm sure, I can do the translation work to C# on my own then.

Comment: I added implementation. If you need not a smooth gradient, but discrete by 10%, then you need to change the step.

Comment: @Nuzhny Cheers! I added the C# implementaion to your answer, which was luckily no trouble at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementation on C++:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("lena.jpg");

int startBlend = 3 * img.rows / 4;
double alpha = 1.0;
double step = 1.0 / (img.rows - startBlend);
for (int y = startBlend; y < img.rows; ++y)
{
    img.row(y) *= alpha;
    alpha -= step;
}

cv::imshow("img", img);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

Result:

[image]